# Do I need to put a tank and pressure switch in my apartment from main dwelling?

Tags: electrical, plumbing

My main dwelling has basement with well run water to pressure tank and switch.  No way to run from basement.  So will I just tee off from well and put pressure tank and switch in the one bedroom apt? I am trying to run water to one bedroom apartment from same pump and well.

Comment: Who's your electric utility? Both they and your AHJ may have something to say about an apartment's (ADU's, to use modern terms) water being supplied by a pump powered by the panel for the main house.  (See NEC 210.25(B) for more details)

Comment: A drawing of the proposed plumbing layout might be useful to help others envision what you're describing.